# Rewriting /foo to /foo.php doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want users to be able to go to /foo and have /foo.php displayed. A quick search on Google came up with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

For some reason, however, this doesn't work. I keep getting a 404 error, even though I know the .php file exists. I searched and searched for an answer, but it seems to work fine for everyone else.

I commented out the other rules, by the way, so nothing is conflicting with this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer! Apparently this is a problem with 1and1's server configuration. This article explains the problem: http://tips.webdesign10.com/web-hosting/why-you-should-never-use-1and1-com-hosting

The first comment also happens to be the solution. Here's the rule that works:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Still no luck. Keep getting the 404 page - I have no idea what's going on, that looks like it should work...

Comment: Did you set AllowOverride All for that directory in the apache settings?

Comment: I tried AllowOverride All again with your solution, but now I'm getting an Internal Server Error for everything, even random url's. It could be because my server doesn't allow AllowOverride: http://faq.1and1.com/scripting_languages_supported/htaccess/4.html

Comment: Yep, I started thinking maybe it has something to do with 1and1 then I found that page. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add the directive [AllowOverride All](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#allowoverride) in your apache configuration or maybe you need to add [RewriteEngine On](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) at the very beginning of your .htaccess file

Comment: I already have `RewriteEngine On` and `AllowOverride All` did fix it.

Comment: Correction: *didn't fix it. Though I do get Internal Server Errors for everything instead, which is strange.

Answer (score 1):

You need this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php
```

Comment: Yeah, and I see no reason why it wouldn't work. Very weird... :S

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use apache's `MultiViews` option:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this issue when you use `.htaccess` in a subfolder. Fix it by using full paths from the web root in your `.htaccess` file. For instance, in the folder `http://www.mysite.com/test/` your `.htaccess` file would look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1.php
```

*-not tested, might need tweaking-*

Comment: The .htaccess file is in the root folder, and all the files I'm requesting are also in the root, so that's not a problem.